# Retrieve data in keychain for particular service not working in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, keychain

I'm storing username and password in keychain.  Here's my code

To save and fetch

I'm trying to store multiple username and passwords using service

When login button clicked

```
[keychain setObject:@"facebookLogin" forKey:(id)kSecAttrService];
[keychain setObject:username forKey:(id)kSecAttrAccount];
[keychain setObject:password forKey:(id)kSecValueData];

[keychain setObject:@"appLogin" forKey:(id)kSecAttrService];
[keychain setObject:username forKey:(id)kSecAttrAccount];
[keychain setObject:password forKey:(id)kSecValueData];
```

When show button clicked

```
NSLog(@"%@", [keychain objectForKey:(id)kSecAttrAccount]);
NSLog(@"%@", [keychain objectForKey:(id)kSecValueData]);
```

How to fetch the username and password which is stored for facebook login and app login?

And I want to store cookie value.

```
[keychain setObject:@"cookieString" forKey:(id)kSecAttrService];
[keychain setObject:myCookie forKey:(id)kSecValueData];
```

Is this is a right way to store the values?

Any help appreciated...

Comment: Use `PDKeychainBindings` in iOS as beautiful [explained with coding example here](http://www.programmingcrew.in/2015/08/save-value-in-keychain-ios-application.html).

Comment: I'm using Apple's KeychainWrapper Can't we do with it?

Answer (score 1):

**This should work:**

**Saving an item to Keychain:**

```
KeychainItemWrapper *login = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"login" accessGroup:nil];

[wrapper setObject:username1 forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccount];
[wrapper setObject:password1 forKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData];
[wrapper setObject:kSecAttrAccessibleAlwaysThisDeviceOnly forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessible];

KeychainItemWrapper *facebookLogin = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"facebooklogin" accessGroup:nil];

[wrapper setObject:username2 forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccount];
[wrapper setObject:password2 forKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData];
[wrapper setObject:kSecAttrAccessibleAlwaysThisDeviceOnly forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessible];
```

**Retrieving an item from Keychain:**

```
// Create respective KeychainItemWrapper objects with identifiers you want to retrieve from

KeychainItemWrapper *login = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"login" accessGroup:nil];

NSData *passwordData1 = [login objectForKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData];
NSString *passwordString1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:passwordData1 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", passwordString1);

KeychainItemWrapper *facebookLogin = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"facebooklogin" accessGroup:nil];

NSData *passwordData2 = [facebookLogin objectForKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData];
NSString *passwordString2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:passwordData2 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", passwordString2);
```

Use `initWithIdentifier` to store items for different categories as you like. You can choose to include or omit `kSecAttrService` as you have used in your question. `initWithIdentifier` is enough and good.

**NOTE**

Here, `kSecAttrAccessible` is really important, 'cause a keychain item has various levels of security of access to it. If your phone has touchId/passcode enabled, use this constant(**kSecAttrAccessibleAlwaysThisDeviceOnly**) to access keychain item from anywhere, i.e., without unlocking your device.

Comment: I'm storing two username & passwords because I have two logins (social & own) in my app and If I store it with different service name the old value gets overridden because the key value is same.  How can we store both and retreive with the service name?

Comment: Please check my updated answer. That should work well for your requirement of adding multiple categories of items to keychain.

Answer (score 0):

Since iOS 10.3 beta 2 an app's keychain entries will be deleted when the app gets uninstalled. Confirmed in the [Apple Developer Forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/73850).